# iOs: What would be the right way to set the Model object in this simple table view app?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Don't want to tell you how much time I spend trying to solve this apparently simple task. 
After finishing iOs Big Nerd Ranch guide, I decide to create a simple app to strengthen my knowledge of UITalbeViews.

Here is the app structure: 
In the app there are two view controllers. 
Main view controller is a UITableView with a set of numbered questions in each cell. 
Each table cell has an accessory type "Detail Disclosure Button". 
Clicking on the cell reveals second View Controller's view. On that view, there is simple comment (details) for that question (Label). 
My question is, what is the right way to set the Model object so that questions will be listed in a consecutive order, and tapping on them will reveal the **right** comment. 
At which point the array of questions with details should be set? 
And how to set such array so that latter when can put all questions in order?

Here is my code. 
The Model object Question.h :

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface Question : NSObject

   @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * question; @property
   (nonatomic, copy) NSString * details;

   +(id)createQuestion;    
   -(id)initWithQuestion:(NSString*)question details:(NSString*)details;  

   @end
```

Question.m:

```
#import "Question.h"

@implementation Question
@synthesize question, details;

+(id)createQuestion
{
        NSArray *arrayOfQuestions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     @"1. Question 1",
                                     @"2. Question 2",
                                     @"3. Question 3",
                                     @"4. Question 4",
                                     @"5. Question 5",
                                     @"6. Question 6",
                                     @"7. Question 7",
                                     @"8. Question 8", nil];

        NSArray *arrayOfDetails = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   @"Comment 1",
                                   @"Comment 2",
                                   @"Comment 3",
                                   @"Comment 4",
                                   @"Comment 5",
                                   @"Comment 6",
                                   @"Comment 8",
                                   @"Comment 9", nil];

        // this is the point when something should be done. But I can't understand, if this method should return a single "Question" object, or an array of objects. 

        return newQuestion;

    }
}

-(id)initWithQuestion:(NSString*)question details:(NSString*)details
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setQuestion:question];
        [self setDetails:details]; 
    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

The main controller MainTableViewController.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MainTableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

MainTableViewController.m:

```
#import "MainTableViewController.h"
#import "DetailsViewController.h"

@implementation MainTableViewController

- (id) init
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
        UINavigationItem *n = [self navigationItem];

        [n setTitle:@"Questions"];

//maybe an array of questions should be created here? 

    }
    return self;
}

-(id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [self init];
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 8;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                   reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    int row =[indexPath row];

    // code for setting the title's of cells goes in here

    }
    return cell;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView*) aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailsViewController *detailsViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc] init];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];
}

@end
```

DetailsViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailsViewController : UIViewController
{
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *details;

}
@end
```

DetailsViewController.m:

```
#import "DetailsViewController.h"

@implementation DetailsViewController

@end
```

In the book there similar app and there there is also a "Store" object is created and it is responsible for creating an array of Model objects. 
I wanted to avoid creating of the "Store" object, and put all code in the MainTabeleViewController.

Thank you for your time, 
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: This question seems a little more appropriate for Code Review, I think.

Comment: @nhgrif what is Code Review?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions  It's more geared for longer form questions such as this.

Comment: @nhgrif: This question isn't on-topic for CR.  The OP is asking how to solve specific problems, so it belongs here.  It doesn't matter if the question is "longer form."  This isn't at all a review request.

Comment: @nhgrif By first glance, I can understand your feeling that it belongs on CR. However, in the code above there are comments like `//maybe an array of questions should be created here?` and `// this is the point when something should be done. But I can't understand, if this method should return a single "Question" object, or an array of objects.`. This indicates that this code is not **fully implemented**. In which case, it is a no-no for CR.

Comment: I see.  I didn't catch that.  In this case then, this question should probably be narrowed down a bit.  As is, it's a bit broad for SO.

Answer (score 1):

*what is the right way to set the Model object so that questions will be listed in a consecutive order,*
The questions will be listed in the order you specify in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

*and tapping on them will reveal the right comment.*
You need to tell the second controller which item was selected. Check here http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/passing-data-between-view-controllers/

*At which point the array of questions with details should be set?*
The questions and details (the model) should be created when your program starts (or at least when the first object that uses it is created). In your case, the **init** is a good place to initialize your model.

*And how to set such array so that latter when can put all questions in order?*
You should maintain your model throughout its life-cycle, if you need to re-order your array, you would need to provide the logic for that, and decide when to to that.

EDIT:
First of all your method +(id)createQuestion looks weird, I would just remove it. Your model is weird in the first place because your object is called Question, but you are instantiating some arrays for many questions... 
Your Question object should be just that, a question, so in the init method you just assign or copy the passed initialization parameters and that's it.

Then you create an array of quesion objects, something like

```
NSMutableArray *myQuestions = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0; i<5, i++)
{
    Question *question = [[Question alloc] initWithQuestion:@"question" answer:@"answer"];
    [myQuestions addObject:question];
}
```

Comment: Sorry @merlevede, but i still have no clue how to create question object in the "creteQuestion" method. Should be something like:         
    Question *newQuestion = [[self alloc] initWithQuestion:[arrayOfQuestions [path row]] details:[arrayOfDetails [path row]]];'

Comment: Ok, I guess i'm trying to copy logic from an example program in the book, and therefore having problems. Using that code that you wrote, how i can create 100 questions and 100 answers? that's why i create arrays.

Comment: I can't answer that question because that's part of your design, I mean, there are 1000 ways of doing it, you need to decide the right one for you. Anyway... I would create 100 questions, and let the answer be a property of the question. So I don't have to create 100 answers separately.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know guys and gals how did you spend today's beautiful Saturday, but I spend it in search for an answer to my question. 
And I'am happy with the way i'm finishing this day - by writing this very answer to my question.

@PeacefulWarrior helped me to find a solution by directing to this repo on github.com: 
https://github.com/timd/Pro-iOS-TableViews

That alone, forced me to finally figure out how the heck the github works and how to "fork" repos using simple commands on terminal.

Logic for this app should be following: 
We leave the Model object as it is, without creating complicated class methods in the .m file (createQuestion). 
We also don't put the code for creating an array (the "for" loop) of "Question" objects into the controller's .m file. 
And all those things don't take place in the "Store" object.

Instead, it's all happens in the AppDelegate.m file. 
The loop that creates a bunch of "Question" object is placed in the "application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:" 
Inside that loop we still use a custom method that creates the Question objects - something similar what I was trying to do in the "createQuestion" method. 
We declare that custom method also inside the AppDelegate.m file.

I also was wondering how we can create a "creation" method, that will be taking consecutive strings from two arrays and match them 1st to 1st, 2nd to 2nd, etc. Since the order is very important in my case. 
The answer is - give a "creation" method an argument, a simple integer "index". 
Latter, when we are using that creation method in the loop (in the "application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: "method), we use that argument as the "loop's" integer. 
Enough talking, check the code:

The Model. 
Question.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Question : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * question;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * details;

@end
```

Question.m:

```
#import "Question.h"

@implementation Question
@synthesize question, details;

@end
```

The Controller. 
MainTableViewController.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MainTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (atomic, copy) NSArray *tableData;

@end
```

MainTableViewController.m:

```
#import "MainTableViewController.h"
#import "DetailsViewController.h"
#import "Question.h"

@implementation MainTableViewController

@synthesize tableData;

- (id) init
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
        UINavigationItem *n = [self navigationItem];
        [n setTitle:@"Questions"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [self init];
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.tableData != nil) {
        return [self.tableData count];
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                   reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    Question *ques = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = ques.question;

    return cell;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView*) aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailsViewController *detailsViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc] init];
        detailsViewController.question= [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];
}

@end
```

DetailsViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Question.h"

@interface DetailsViewController : UIViewController

@property (atomic, strong) Question *question;
@property (atomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *details;

@end
```

DetailsViewController.m:

```
#import "DetailsViewController.h"

@interface DetailsViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailsViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.details.text = self.question.details;
}

@end
```

And now the AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Question;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, strong) NSMutableArray *tableData;

-(Question *)createWithDetailsIndex:(int)index;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainTableViewController.h"
#import "Question.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize tableData;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    NSUInteger numberOfQuestions = 8;
    self.tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberOfQuestions];

    for (NSUInteger i=0 ; i< numberOfQuestions; i++) {
        Question *question1 = [self createWithDetailsIndex:i];
        [self.tableData addObject:question1];
    }

    MainTableViewController *mainTableViewController = [[MainTableViewController alloc] init];

    mainTableViewController.tableData = (NSArray *)self.tableData;

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainTableViewController];

    [[self window] setRootViewController:navController];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}


-(Question *)createWithDetailsIndex:(int)index

{
    Question *q = [[Question alloc] init];

    NSArray *arrayOfQuestions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 @"1. Questions?",
                                 @"2. Questions?",
                                 @"3. Questions?",
                                 @"4. Questions?",
                                 @"5. Questions?",
                                 @"6. Questions?",
                                 @"7. Questions?",
                                 @"8. Questions?", nil];


    NSArray *arrayOfDetails = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               @"1th question, place description in here",
                               @"2nd question, place description in here",
                               @"3rd question, place description in here",
                               @"4th question, place description in here",
                               @"5th question, place description in here",
                               @"6th question, place description in here",
                               @"7th question, place description in here",
                               @"8th question, place description in here", nil];

    q.question = [arrayOfQuestions objectAtIndex:index];
    q.details= [arrayOfDetails objectAtIndex:index];

    return q;
}

@end
```

Thank you for your time, and good luck with your table!